# Loop through all the sentences and return 1 if the length of array > 1 else 0

Tags: python, arrays, indexing, return, position

```
def noun_verb():
 for text_id, text in enumerate(news_df['headline'].values):
    words = [item[0] for item in sentence_tags]   
 
for word in words:
label = [item[0].index for item in sentence_tags]
tags_to_label = [] 

verb = False
first_noun = False
second_noun = False

for lab in zip(label):
  if t.startswith('NN'):
    tags_to_label.append(lab)
    first_noun = True

  elif t.startswith('NN') and first_noun:
    tags_to_label.append(lab)
    second_noun = True

  elif t.startswith('VB') and (first_noun or second_noun):
    break 
  
  elif (first_noun or second_noun):
    tags_to_label = []
    verb = False
    first_noun, second_noun = False, False
```

tags_to_label is an array that carries the index and position of the Nouns in the sentence. For example,

> a local man charged for theft -> (local NN man NN) , tags_to_label ->
> [2,3]

```
buffer = []
 if len(tags_to_label) > 1:
    buffer.append(1)
 else:
    buffer.append(0)
    print(buffer)
```

Im trying to use a return method looping through all the sentences and if the rule applies to the sentence return 1 else 0 but all my outputs are:

```
[0]
[0]
[0]
[0]
```

Does this mean tags_to_label is always empty? If so is there a way to fix this? What I am trying to achieve is return 1 if values exists in the tags_to_label array else 0 if there are no values in the array.

Comment: you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Just a sanity check, the `print(buffer)` sits inside the `else` clause thus it would not print if length > 1. Is it intended?

Comment: @lpounng print(buffer) to check if it is printing anything. is that the wrong way?

Comment: @Beginner I mean `print(buffer)` seems over-indented, so it only prints inside `else`.